# Struct Declaration Issue in main.cpp for C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

So I have been building a program that would act as a gradebook, and there is an issue with a particular function in main.cpp.
This is the code (And this is C++, by the way):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Classes
{
    double accousticGuitarEnsemble;
    double biology;
    double english;
    double enteringAKehillah;
    double geometry;
    double hebrew;
    double worldHistory;
};

void gradeEditor()
{
    cout << "GradeBook 1.0" << endl; 
    newGrade:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering today? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered;
    getline(cin, classBeingEntered);
    Classes Eitan;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade;
    cin >> grade;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered == "accousticGuitarEnsemble")
        Eitan.accousticGuitarEnsemble = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "biology")
        Eitan.biology = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "english")
        Eitan.english = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "enteringAKehillah")
        Eitan.enteringAKehillah = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "geometry")
        Eitan.geometry = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "hebrew")
        Eitan.hebrew = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "worldHistory")
        Eitan.worldHistory = grade;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade;
}

void choice()
{
    choiceBack:
    cout << "Do you want to edit another grade? Press Y or N: ";
    char chChoice;
    cin >> chChoice;
    switch (chChoice) {
        case 'Y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor();
            goto choiceBack;
            } while (chChoice == 'Y');
        case 'N':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
        case 'y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor();
            goto choiceBack;
            } while (chChoice == 'y');
        case 'n':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
    }
}

void printGrades(Classes Eitan)
{
    cout << "Accoustic Guitar Ensemble: " << Eitan.accousticGuitarEnsemble << endl;
    cout << "Biology: " << Eitan.biology << endl;
    cout << "English: " << Eitan.english << endl;
    cout << "Entering a Kehillah: " << Eitan.enteringAKehillah << endl;
    cout << "Geometry: " << Eitan.geometry << endl;
    cout << "Hebrew: " << Eitan.hebrew << endl;
    cout << "World History: " << Eitan.worldHistory << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

int main()
{
    gradeEditor();
    choice();
    printGrades();
}
```

However, for printGrades(), I get this error:
**error C2660: 'printGrades' : function does not take 0 arguments
IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call**
Both of these errors occur on Line 92, where printGrades is called in main.
No matter what I put in the printGrades parentheses, it comes up with an undeclared identifier error.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Also, does anyone see anything else wrong with this code?

UPDATE: I have fixed the code (Sort of). It compiles and runs, and this is what it is now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Classes
{
    double acousticGuitarEnsemble;
    double biology;
    double english;
    double enteringAKehillah;
    double geometry;
    double hebrew;
    double worldHistory;
};

Classes gradeEditor()
{
    Classes eitan;
    cout << "GradeBook 1.0" << endl; 
    newGrade:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering today? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered;
    getline(cin, classBeingEntered);
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade;
    cin >> grade;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered == "acousticGuitarEnsemble")
        eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "biology")
        eitan.biology = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "english")
        eitan.english = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "enteringAKehillah")
        eitan.enteringAKehillah = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "geometry")
        eitan.geometry = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "hebrew")
        eitan.hebrew = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "worldHistory")
        eitan.worldHistory = grade;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade;
}

void choice()
{
    choiceBack:
    cout << "Do you want to edit another grade? Press Y or N: ";
    char chChoice;
    cin >> chChoice;
    switch (chChoice) {
        case 'Y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor();
            goto choiceBack;
            } while (chChoice == 'Y');
        case 'N':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
        case 'y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor();
            goto choiceBack;
            } while (chChoice == 'y');
        case 'n':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
    }
}

void printGrades(Classes eitan)
{
    cout << "Acoustic Guitar Ensemble: " << eitan.acousticGuitarEnsemble << endl;
    cout << "Biology: " << eitan.biology << endl;
    cout << "English: " << eitan.english << endl;
    cout << "Entering a Kehillah: " << eitan.enteringAKehillah << endl;
    cout << "Geometry: " << eitan.geometry << endl;
    cout << "Hebrew: " << eitan.hebrew << endl;
    cout << "World History: " << eitan.worldHistory << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

int main()
{
    Classes eitan = gradeEditor();
    choice();
    printGrades(eitan);
}
```

However, when I run the program, I can enter in one grade, but then the entire process "breaks" and becomes irreparable.
If anyone can help me any further, please run my program and leave a comment below.

Comment: Because it's bugging me:  "acoustic", not "accoustic".

Comment: Make classes global, or pass it to each function by reference or address; (Classes &classes) or (Classes *classes). As John3136 mentioned, the local instance in gradeEditor is effectively useless. Also, add curlies around the two statements in the final "else" clause of gradeEditor.

Comment: There are many errors in your code. You should start with something simpler, and extend it once you have tested it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `printGrades()` method expects an argument of type `Classes`, but you don't pass it one.

Also suggest making your variable names/parameters start with lowercase letters so they don't look like types. i.e. `void printGrades(Classes Eitan)` should be `void printGrades(Classes eitan)`

The only instance of `Classes` is local in `gradeEditor()` so nothing gets "stored anywhere".

And last but not least:

**YOU ARE USING GOTO**

Comment: It's not that the op is using goto, but how he's using goto.

Comment: @bvj No no. in my book it's the fact that he's using `goto`

Comment: Yet it's part of the language. Nonetheless, GSDs rule.

Comment: @John3136 I'm using goto primarily for jumping back to a spot in the same code block. There's no better way to do that, right? Also, after implementing an argument for printGrades(Classes eitan), I have received the following errors: "error C2059: syntax error : ')'" "error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'eitan'" "error C2275: 'Classes' : illegal use of this type as an expression" "IntelliSense: expected a ')'" "IntelliSense: type name is not allowed". Any other suggestions? (The errors are all on Line 92)

Comment: @DJHead-On: There are plenty of better ways to do it.  For example, you could simply return a bool indicating whether the user wants to continue.  Then in main, you can say `do { gradeEditor(); } while (choice());`.

Answer (score 2):

Create an object of **struct Classes** in **main()** and pass the object as an argument to **printGrades()**. Function **printGrades()** expects a structure object as its argument according to the function definition. Something like this.

```
Classes cl;
printGrades(cl);
```

And even if you do the above thing the **printGrades()** function will print garbage values as the structure objects are not initialized so I would suggest you the change the return type of **gradeEditor()** from **void** to **struct** type which return the object to the structure and copy that object in **c1**. Something like this would be more appropriate and you can remove the methoid **choice** also

```
Classes gradeEditor()
{
/* Function Body*/
  return Eitan;
}

main()
{
   Classes cl;


   char choice;
   do{
         c1=gradeEditor();
         cout << "Do you want to edit another grade? Press Y or N: ";
     }while((choice=getch())!='n' || (choice=getch())!='N');
   cout<<"Printing Grades: "<<endl;
   printGrades(cl);

}
```

And in the **gradeEditor** you are using **goto**, watch it carefully, the control will never come out of the gradeEditor() method as you haven't specified any condition to come out.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work fine for you if you are using it on a system other tha windows you also need to include `#include <cstdlib>` for using `system("pause")`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Classes
{
    double accousticGuitarEnsemble;
    double biology;
    double english;
    double enteringAKehillah;
    double geometry;
    double hebrew;
    double worldHistory;
};

void gradeEditor()
{
    cout << "GradeBook 1.0" << endl;
    newGrade:
    cout << "Which grade are you entering today? (Use the following format: exampleFormat): ";
    string classBeingEntered;
    getline(cin, classBeingEntered);
    Classes Eitan;
    cout << "Enter the new grade: ";
    double grade;
    cin >> grade;
    cout << "Grade entered." << endl;
    if (classBeingEntered == "accousticGuitarEnsemble")
        Eitan.accousticGuitarEnsemble = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "biology")
        Eitan.biology = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "english")
        Eitan.english = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "enteringAKehillah")
        Eitan.enteringAKehillah = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "geometry")
        Eitan.geometry = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "hebrew")
        Eitan.hebrew = grade;
    else if (classBeingEntered == "worldHistory")
        Eitan.worldHistory = grade;
    else
        cout << "Invalid class name. Try again." << endl;
        goto newGrade;
}

void choice()
{
    choiceBack:
    cout << "Do you want to edit another grade? Press Y or N: ";
    char chChoice;
    cin >> chChoice;
    switch (chChoice) {
        case 'Y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor();
            goto choiceBack;
            } while (chChoice == 'Y');
        case 'N':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
        case 'y':
            cout << "Alright then!" << endl;
            do {
            gradeEditor();
            goto choiceBack;
            } while (chChoice == 'y');
        case 'n':
            cout << "Printing grades..." << endl;
            break;
    }
}

void printGrades(Classes Eitan)
{
    cout << "Accoustic Guitar Ensemble: " << Eitan.accousticGuitarEnsemble << endl;
    cout << "Biology: " << Eitan.biology << endl;
    cout << "English: " << Eitan.english << endl;
    cout << "Entering a Kehillah: " << Eitan.enteringAKehillah << endl;
    cout << "Geometry: " << Eitan.geometry << endl;
    cout << "Hebrew: " << Eitan.hebrew << endl;
    cout << "World History: " << Eitan.worldHistory << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

int main()
{
    Classes Eitan;
    gradeEditor();
    choice();
    printGrades( Eitan );
}
```

Comment: Test your code. There are still a few problems that require correction.

Comment: I have just corrected the syntax buddy not verified the logic

Comment: bvj is correct @yanivx. On line 93, I have received this error: "error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'eitan' used"

Comment: @DJHead-On That is because your logic is wrong. You never initialize that variable. You have to make sure you do that.

Comment: @juanchopanza And how would you suppose that I could do that?

Comment: @DJHead-On I will give you a hint: `gradeEditor()` acts on a local `Classes` variable. Whatever it does with it has no effect on the rest of the program.

Comment: @yanivx Well this is C++

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried making Classes eitan a global variable, but it didn't work.

Comment: @DJHead-On I know that its C++ which compiler are you using

Comment: @yanivx I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012, as indicated in the tags that I included